# (Verification) Ordered Basis Consists of Subspace $\rightarrow$ $Direct\;Sum$ of Subspaces

Tags: proof-verification

Let $W_1, W_2, W_3,..., W_k$ be subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space V.

**Claim**

There $\exists $ $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2\cup..\cup\gamma_k$ which is an ordered basis for $V$ ($\gamma_i$ is an ordered basis for $W_i$)

$\rightarrow$ $\;\;$$V = W_1\oplus W_2...\oplus W_k$,

**Proof**

For each $i$, let $\gamma_i$ be an ordered basis for $W_i$ s.t. $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2\cup..\cup\gamma_k$is an ordered basis for V.

Then $V= span(\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2\cup..\cup\gamma_k)= span(\gamma_1)+span(\gamma_2)+\cdot\cdot\cdot+span(\gamma_k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}W_i$

Fix $j\;(1\le j\le k)$, and suppose that, for some nonzero vector $v\ \in V$,

$v\in W_j\cap\sum_{i\neq j}W_i$.

Then

$v\in W_j=span(\gamma_j)$ and $v\in \sum_{i \neq j}W_i = span(\cup_{i \neq j} \gamma_i)$

Hence $v$ is a nontrivial linear combination of both $\gamma_j$and$\cup_{i \neq j} \gamma_i$,

so that $v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of  $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2\cup..\cup\gamma_k$

in more than one way. But it contradicts to $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2\cup..\cup\gamma_k$ is a basis for $V$

Thus we conclude that  $ W_j\cap\sum_{i\neq j}W_i = \{0\}$

Comment: Maybe your $\gamma_i$ should be disjoint?

Comment: @tommyxu3 at first I supposed like you but it wasn't needed to be. secret is on the statement that "$\beta$ is basis for V if and only if $v \in V$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of $\beta$"

Comment: Let $V=\Bbb{R}^3,~W_1=x-y$ plane, $W_2=y-z$ plane and $\gamma_1=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\},~\gamma_2=\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}.$ Then $W_1+W_2$ is not an internal direct sum.

Comment: @tommyxu3 it's interesting.. could you pick up the absurd point from my proof?

Comment: If some $\gamma_i$ intersect, then your conclusion that $v$ has more than one expressions may fail, for the two may be identical.

Comment: @tommyxu3 this claim is about just existence not about unique existence. I think so my proof is correct

Comment: What I pointed out is exactly on your condition of existence, and you can see why it doesn't work by the counterexample.